# How do I get the http response/server code from each request in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-http-client

Using the Zend Framework Http client, how do I get the http response/server code from each request? I am getting the body just fine, but the response code would be nice too.

Comment: Found the answer:

$response->getStatus();

Comment: You should add that as an answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
$response->getStatus();
```

Comment: or `$response->getCode()` to get sth. like (int) 404, am I right?